# ELI5 what are erasure codes?

Tags: sharding, erasure-codes

Reading this [article](https://medium.com/nearprotocol/unsolved-problems-in-blockchain-sharding-2327d6517f43), I understand that erasure codes are a potential solution to the data availability issue in sharding. That is, a light node can have higher certainty regarding the contents of a block when erasure codes are used.

However, I couldn't find a straightforward explanation of the concept. Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 2):

ELI5:

- You have 2 numbers, X and Y, each in an envelope.
- In a 3rd envelope, you store **X+Y**.
- This 3rd envelope can be considered the erasure code.
- You will always be able to compute X and Y by only losing 1 envelope.
- The concept: **to avoid losing data, you store additional data in a smart way**.  (In the example above, it would not help if the 3rd envelope stored X, because losing both envelopes that had X, will mean that X is lost forever.)

The [source](https://www.rubrik.com/blog/erasure-coding-rubrik-doubled-capacity-cluster) of the above example has a more interesting case.  The data is X, Y, Z, W.  The erasure code of **X+Y+Z+W** and **X+2Y+4Z+8W** allows the 4 pieces of data to be recovered if any 2 pieces are lost.

---

Related non-ELI5:

http://web.archive.org/web/20190620141650/https://github.com/ethereum/research/wiki/A-note-on-data-availability-and-erasure-coding

https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.09044